# How to calculate data of api service and to display in a card in angular component

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I want to display in a card in angular project for example the count number of row . To get the data from mysql i'm using a service.

here is the service data :

```
 private _postsURL = "http://localhost:3003/all";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    }

   getcount(): Observable<ICustomer[]> {
   return this.http
      .get(this._postsURL)
      .map((response: Response) => {
          return <ICustomer[]>response.json();
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

component.ts

```
        getcount(): void {
        this.apiSerivce.getcount()
        .subscribe(
          resultArray => this._count = [resultArray[0]],
          error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
         )
         }

       ngOnInit(): void {
       this.getcount();
```

component.html

```
           <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let post of _count">
                        <h2 class="m-b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-buffer text- 
               warning"></i></h2>
                        <h3 class="">{{post}}</h3>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Total Earnings</h6> 
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ngb-progressbar [showValue]="false" 
             type="warning" [value]="50"></ngb-progressbar>
```

I want to populate the card only with the value fetch from api.

Comment: first of all a question, why are you using `Http` instead of `HttpClient`?

Comment: you should include an example of the data currently received, i.e. what is there when you console log the resultArray response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API response is an asynchronous event and ngOnInit method execution completes before it gets response from backend call so, you should render the card section view only if `_count` variable binding got value in it and you can achieve it by adding **ngIf** directive on root-card html element as below.

```
  <div class="card" *ngIf="_count?.length > 0">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let post of _count">
                        <h2 class="m-b-0"><i class="mdi mdi-buffer text- 
               warning"></i></h2>
                        <h3 class="">{{post}}</h3>
                        <h6 class="card-subtitle">Total Earnings</h6> 
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ngb-progressbar [showValue]="false" 
             type="warning" [value]="50"></ngb-progressbar>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined !

Comment: http://localhost:3003/all  this api call return anly one number : 2 for exaple and i want to display this result in card

Comment: app.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '',
             user: '',
             password: '*',
              database: '',
    })
    const queryString = "SELECT COUNT(*) as Totali FROM `customer` WHERE country='Austria'"
    connection.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
    
      }

Comment: @Alia There was a typo in example and just corrected. It should `*ngIf="_count?.length > 0"`

Comment: <div class="card" *ngIf="_count?.length > 0"> using ngIF inside class card i cannot see the card :(

Comment: What you expect to render until you fetch value from api?

Comment: Actually you can add `ngIf` condition to any html element which you don't want to get rendered until it fetches data from backend.